# Can I use blazor (MIT) and mysql community (GPL) for commercial purposes?

Tags: licensing, license-compatibility, license-recommendation, license

If I sell my program in blazor and use mysql community for the data layer... my blazor program would be under the GPL?, that is, would I have to deliver my source code of my blazor made in program?

Comment: Please describe in detail the link/interface/API between your code and the GPL-licensed code. Without that your question is impossible to answer.